# Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/$metadata'

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, metadata

thought I'd try to see if anyone has seen this or something similar as I'm not sure where to start looking. I have a bunch of web services which have been fine for the longest time but now my server guy said they gave out an error that I've never seen before. Any ideas / things to look at?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          6/12/2012 6:57:03 AM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Server
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 6/12/2012 6:57:03 AM 
Event time (UTC): 6/12/2012 1:57:03 PM 
Event ID: 691c9c8fabeb4701aa31488d6db060ce 
Event sequence: 123578 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: domain
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: D:\Sites\webroot\ 
Machine name: Server

Process information: 
Process ID: 2456 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\AppPool_AID1651 

Exception information: 
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/$metadata'.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add the following to your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

My web service also logs `Event Code 3005`. I'm calling my web service using JQuery `$.ajax()`, which produces two http requests. The first request is an "OPTIONS" request, and it is met with an `500 Internal Server Error` message. This is the one that's being logged with `Event Code 3005`. The second request is a "POST" request, which is met with the correct answer from the web service.

I haven't been successful in my attempts to keep the "OPTIONS" requests from being logged as errors, but I hope this information is helpful to you anyway.

My error log also matches yours with this phrase:

> Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in …

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all.